# Flutter - Render Text Class with value of Variable. Possible Type problem?

Tags: flutter, dart

Creating a set of UI Tiles using a sizedBox with nested Text class. Trying to set the Text() class value on ***LINE 20*** to equal a variable (variable is "symbol") of type String. When I replace the Text value with a String ("text placeholder") it compiles without issue. For some reason the Text class doesn't want to render a variable value, only a hard-coded String value.

The lint error in Android Studio says ***"The evaluation of a constant creation must be constant expressions. Try making the constant a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor"***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:GDT360/gdtSymbols.dart';

var symbol = GdtKey().angularity.symbol;

GdtSymbol qgtSymbols = GdtKey as GdtSymbol;

class boxTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const boxTile({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200.0,
      height: 300.0,
      child: const Card(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(symbol,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0XFF07BCE7),
                fontSize: 36
            ),
      )),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Class where the variable value is coming from:

```
class GdtSymbol {
  String name;
  String symbol;
  String translation;

  GdtSymbol({String name, String symbol, String translation}) {
    name = name;
    symbol = symbol;
    translation = translation;
  }

  }

  class GdtKey {
    GdtSymbol angularity = GdtSymbol(name: 'Angularity',
        symbol: '∠',
        translation: 'Angularity Placeholder Definition');

    GdtSymbol arkLength = GdtSymbol(name: 'Ark Length',
        symbol: '⌢',
        translation: 'Ark Length Placeholder Definition');

    GdtSymbol between = GdtSymbol(name: 'Between',
        symbol: '↔',
        translation: 'Between Placeholder Definition');
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1 : remove `const` keyword in front of `Card` 
Step 2 : `construction` of `GdtSymbol` need `this` keyword

```
GdtSymbol({this.name, this.symbol, this.translation}) {
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

var symbol = GdtKey().angularity.symbol;

GdtSymbol qgtSymbols = GdtKey as GdtSymbol;

class boxTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const boxTile({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: 200.0,
        height: 300.0,
        child: Card(
          child: Center(
              child: Text(
            symbol,
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0XFF07BCE7), fontSize: 36),
          )),
        ));
  }
}

class GdtSymbol {
  String name;
  String symbol;
  String translation;

  GdtSymbol({this.name, this.symbol, this.translation}) {
    name = name;
    symbol = symbol;
    translation = translation;
  }
}

class GdtKey {
  GdtSymbol angularity = GdtSymbol(
      name: 'Angularity',
      symbol: '∠',
      translation: 'Angularity Placeholder Definition');

  GdtSymbol arkLength = GdtSymbol(
      name: 'Ark Length',
      symbol: '⌢',
      translation: 'Ark Length Placeholder Definition');

  GdtSymbol between = GdtSymbol(
      name: 'Between',
      symbol: '↔',
      translation: 'Between Placeholder Definition');
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            boxTile(),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks